# How to create a production build using javascriptServices and react+redux template

Tags: webpack, azure-web-app-service, javascriptservices

I would like to deploy my app (using javaScriptServices) for production. In my webpack.config I have added this code:

```
...
var API_URL = {
  development: JSON.stringify('devApiUrl'),
  production: JSON.stringify('prodApiUrl')
}

...

var environment = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'?'production':'development';

...

plugins: [
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({'API_URL': API_URL[environment]})
    ]
...
```

Then in my code, everywhere API_URL is found is replaced for it's actual value(eg: devApiUrl ), so far so good. I am deploying my app to an Azure App Service, but always, the API_URL is set for development, and I do not know how to change NODE_ENV. I did create a variable in the Azure service called NODE_ENV and have setted to 'production', but did not work. Can someone help me?

Comment: It is more convenient to use two different scripts build production/build development, environment variable may  behave unexpected.

Comment: Males sense, the thing is that i do not know how to manage this with javascriptservices